# Find all objects inside a Package or Stored proc

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm not sure if this question make sense. But thought of asking this here.

Assume I have procedure like below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COLA INTO COL **Payment**.TAB1 ;
  SELECT COLA INTO COL **Checkout**.TAB1 ;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

In the above code. The proc is there in the schema "Order" as you can see this proc is using the data of Payment and Checkout. So here Payment and checkout are different schema.

My quesiton is,

Is there a way to identify to get the list of ther schema being used inside the procedure or package?

Please help out.

Comment: Well I got the answer                                                            SELECT * FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES WHERE OWNER = USER AND NAME= 'PROCEDURE1' AND REFERENCED_OWNER NOT IN ('SYS', USER);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have this procedure:

```
create procedure my_proc
is
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_cursor for select * from all_objects;
  close l_cursor;
  open l_cursor for select * from all_tables;
  close l_cursor;
  open l_cursor for select * from user_objects;
  close l_cursor;
  open l_cursor for select * from user_tables;
  close l_cursor;
end my_proc;
```

So both implicit and explicit references can be found like this:

```
select NAME, referenced_name, referenced_type, referenced_owner from all_dependencies
 where name = 'MY_PROC'

NAME    REFERENCED_NAME                 REFERENCED_TYPE  REFERENCED_OWNER
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_PROC STANDARD                        PACKAGE          SYS
MY_PROC USER_TABLES                     SYNONYM          PUBLIC
MY_PROC USER_OBJECTS                    SYNONYM          PUBLIC
MY_PROC ALL_TABLES                      SYNONYM          PUBLIC
MY_PROC ALL_OBJECTS                     SYNONYM          PUBLIC
MY_PROC SYS_STUB_FOR_PURITY_ANALYSIS    PACKAGE          SYS
```

So REFERENCED_OWNER is the schema that is owner of the object.